Active Miller Clamp vs "Bipolar" Gate Driving (e.g. VGE = ±15 V)
I've been designing an H-bridge inverter (~150 kHz and ~20 kW), and notice that many IGBT half bridge modules (e.g. this one) recommend a VGE of  ±15 V. My understanding is that negative gate drive voltages help avoid accidental turn-on of a switching element due to the Miller Effect.
I know that it's possible to actively clamp this instead, which can allow one to use VGE=0 as the low state instead without accidental turn-on concerns.
My question is, once accidental turn-on is out of the picture, are there other advantages to using a negative VGE? Intuitively it seems like it should allow for faster switch off times (and hence less switching losses), but I can't find any information about this.

This question has a fair number of answers on it now, but none of them are great.  There's lots of circumstantial ideas, sure -- I can enumerate those too, myself -- but I haven't answered because I don't know the particular circumstances that manufacturers are targeting. For example, I would like to see (and will gladly upvote and promote) an answer addressing why -15V, why not -10 or -4V or etc.? Or, which analyzes (in as close to a manufacturer's analysis as possible, or using mfg data/cites) device properties in relation to the gate circuit.

I suspect (short of mfg employees and proprietary data) the latter answer does not exist [in such a public domain as here] -- but I put this as a challenge to readers, and present answerers: prove me wrong!

I would think it would depend on whether your gate driver looks more like a current source/sink in the region where the transistor is switching, or more like a resistor.
In the first case it doesn't matter what the terminal voltage is as far as switching time goes, the current source/sink will have to insert or remove the requisite amount of charge and that's current * time.
In the second case, it will matter, since the current will decrease as the gate-source voltage approaches the terminal voltage.

The issue is that the inductance between the gate driver and the gate itself means that even if the driver produces 0 V, the IGBT itself may have a large positive VGS.
If you can get an active clamp physically close to the VGS -- both the gate and the source it might work -- but then couldn't you just put the driver there.
The -15V means that there is plenty of margin for L.di/dt across the gate wiring to still ensure the IGBT remains off robustly.

Makes sense, thank you!


My question is, once accidental turn-on is out of the picture, are
there other advantages to using a negative VGE?

Yes, it permits faster turn-off times. Consider the input capacitance for the linked module (27 nF). You need to discharge that capacitance as quickly as you can and take the input voltage below the gate threshold voltage of typically 5.8 volts. So, if you use a negative drive to achieve this it will be quicker to drop the input voltage to below 5.8 volts than if you use a 0 volt drive.
In the above I didn't mention reverse transfer capacitance for simplicity but, considering that it's 0.9 nF and, the collector output voltage swing on the low-side device might be (say 500 volts) then, this is somewhat closer to adding 90 nF in parallel with the gate.
That's a simplistic calculation; I've multiplied 0.9 nF by 500/5 to get 90 nF but, it won't be far off.

but I can't find any information about this

It's just evaluating what the RC time constants are; nothing more complex. Of course you could always use a simulator and see for yourself.

For me it's a matter of knowing what to put into the simulator – the datasheets seem give the input capacitance at conditions that seem quite different to the operating ones. And when I try use gate charge I get quite different numbers. But thanks!
